# How to separate a String using a List of words?

Tags: java, string, list, recursion

How could I separate a String using a pre-given List of Strings, separating them by spaces?

Eg:

List of words: `words = {"hello", "how", "are", "you"}`

The string I want to separate: `text = "hellohowareyou"`

```java
public static String separateText(String text, List<String> words) {
    String new_text;

    for (String word : words) {
        if (text.startsWith(word)) {
            String suffix = text.substring(word.length());  //'suffix' is the 'text' without it's first word
            new_text += " " + word;  //add the first word of the 'string'
            separateString(suffix, words);
        }
    }
    
    return new_text;
}
```

And `new_text` should return `hello how are you`

Note that the order of the List `words` could be different and also have more words, like a dictionary.

How could I make this recursion, if needed?

Comment: In accordance to [Oracle's naming conventions for Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) you should name local variables with camelCase.

Comment: Do you have a rule of how to disambiguate if the text is “ihoweverywhere” and the dictionary contains words like [“ever”, “every”, “how”, “however”, “where”, “everywhere”] given the order is not defined?

Comment: My solution will just disambiguate in the order the words are in the words List. Words more to the beginning of the list take priority. If you want longer words to take priority you can sort the words in a natural order descending (or simply by length descending).

Comment: What if the words were ["now", "here", "no", "where"]. How would you split "nowhere"? It is the shortest found word first, so split to "no" and "where"? Must [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) be supported if chosing the shortest word first leads to a dead end - eg if the input was "nownow", chosing "no" would leave "wnow" which can't be split? Or is chosing the shortest word first (if that is the behaviour) guaranteed to not require backtracking?

Comment: @Ma3x sorting wouldn't help much without OP providing us with the distinct set of rules (i.e. `rangeofanorange` cannot be correctly spaced whatever order we provide `[an, of, or, range, orange]`) but besides your solution has O(n * m) time complexity (m - length of text, n - size of the dictionary) I do agree it's at least a good starting point

Comment: That is why I said that my solution takes them in the order they are specified in the words List, which allows OP to achieve a few rulesets. If the OP has a different specification (that cannot be supported just by ordering in the words list and would require a specific implementation, maybe even backtracking), they will let us know. Taking list priority it would split them as "now here" and "range of an or ange" - last word would be incorrectly identified as an unknown word. I am still waiting for OP to even provide any spec updates.

Comment: is `separateString` a typo ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

- You should use StringBuilder if you find yourself repeatedly appending to a string
- Use a while loop to iterate through `text`, remove one word at a time and finish when `text` is empty

```
public static String separateText(String text, List<String> words){
        StringBuilder newTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        outerLoop:
        while(text.length() > 0){
            for(String word : words){
                if(text.startsWith(word)){
                    newTextBuilder.append(word + " ");
                    text = text.substring(word.length());
                    continue outerLoop;
                }
            }
        }

        return newTextBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How could I separate a String using a pre-given List of Strings, separating them by spaces?

Pretty much how you already started. Checking if the remaining text starts with any of the words from the list, remove the starting word and keep the suffix.

You did all that already, but instead of just keeping the suffix and keep iterating you decided to try to call `separateText` recursively.

That is also a possibility, but even just normally iterating in a while loop until the suffix (or remaining text) is empty is enough.

Using a loop like `while (index < text.length())` will work for longer inputs too even if the words are in a different order.

```java
public String separateText(String text, List<String> words){
    if (text == null) return "";
    if (words == null || words.isEmpty()) return text;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    boolean unknownWord = false;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < text.length()) {
        boolean wordFound = false;
        for (String word : words) {
            if (!word.isEmpty() && text.startsWith(word, index)) {
                wordFound = true;
                // move the index ahead just past the last letter of the word found
                index += word.length();
                if (unknownWord) {
                    unknownWord = false;
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
                sb.append(word);
                sb.append(" ");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!wordFound) {
            unknownWord = true;
            sb.append(text.charAt(index));
            index++;
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This will not work as it assumes: a) the `words` dictionary "knows" all the words which may occur inside the text. b) the order of words inside the dictionary is identical to their occurrence in the text. So either `separateText("iamremoteserver", asList("server", "am", "i"))` or `separateText("iamremoteserver", asList("extra"))` would lead to in infinite loop. This can also be improved by using a `StringBuilder` instead of `+` and local variables name needs to be in camel case

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it keeps an infinite loop

Comment: Well I am sorry (to both of the commenters), but you said "Note that the order of the List **words** could be different and also have more words, like a dictionary." You did not say that the input could have other words. If that is the case edit the question to specify it.

Comment: @dshelya About a) I followed OP description, if the specs are different OP will edit his question. b) that is not an assumption at all and it works for any order. As for the StringBuilder I completely agree.

Comment: @Ma3x for the b)  - yeah, my mistake, it will work (though it would place a space as the first character)

Comment: @AfonsoHipólito There, swapped to StringBuilder, made it resilient to various inputs, added support for unknown words, and optimized the iteration to not make substrings. Let me know if this does the job now.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is pretty simple, but it is not memory optimal, because many new `String` is created.

```java
public static String separate(String str, Set<String> words) {
    for (String word : words)
        str = str.replace(word, word + ' ');

    return str.trim();
}
```

**Demo**

```java
Set<String> words = Set.of("hello", "how", "are", "you");
System.out.println(separate("wow hellohowareyouhellohowareyou", words));
// wow hello how are you hello how are you
```

---

Another solution, with `StringBuilder` and looks better to me from the performance view.

```java
public static String separate(String str, Set<String> words) {
    List<String> res = new LinkedList<>();
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        buf.append(str.charAt(i));

        if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' || words.contains(buf.toString())) {
            res.add(buf.toString().trim());
            buf.delete(0, buf.length());
        }
    }

    return String.join(" ", res);
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple (but not recursive). If a word can appear multiple times it won't work as expected.

Comment: @c0der **Afonso Hipólito** asked about recursion **if needed**. There's no need to use recursion here. `str.replace()` replaces **ALL** occurrences, so multiple words will be successfully replaced in the given string.

Comment: You are right. It is tagged with recursion so it is subject to interpretation. In general, the question is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive method try the following:

```
public static String separateText(String text, List<String> words){
    return separateText(text, words, new StringBuilder());
}

public static String separateText(String text, List<String> words, StringBuilder result){

    for(String word : words){
        if (text.startsWith(word)){
           result.append(word).append(" ");
           text = text.substring(word.length());
           ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(words);
           newList.remove(word);
           separateText(text, newList, result);
           break;
        }
    }

    return result.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: btw. `ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(words);` should be `List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(words);`. And this is not efficient, because imagine you have a 1M words, and you copy it for each iteration. It's better to use another collection type here.

Comment: It can be `List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(words);` but I don't see the big benefit. What other collection would you use ?

Comment: `Queue`: remove a word before the recursive call and add it after it.

Comment: I wouldn't do it, nor would I use a recursive solution for 1M words.

Comment: The solution assumes all the words are known and exist in the dictionary. if at least one is unknown - empty result :( Not sure if that's an issue though

Comment: _The solution assumes all the words ... exist in the dictionary_ Yes. There is no way to split to something meaningful if the words are not in the dictionary.  The dictionary may include many other words and also multiple entries of the same word.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // You must sort this by it's length, or you will not have correct result
        // since it may cause match with more shorter words.
        // In this example, it's done
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("hello", "how", "are", "you");
        List<String> detectedWords = new ArrayList<>();
        String text = "hellohowareyou";
        int i = 0;
        while (i < text.length()) {
            Optional<String> wordOpt = Optional.empty();

            for (String word : words) {
                if (text.indexOf(word, i) >= 0) {
                    wordOpt = Optional.of(word);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (wordOpt.isPresent()) {
                String wordFound = wordOpt.get();
                i += wordFound.length();
                detectedWords.add(wordFound);
            }
        }
        String result = String.join(" ", detectedWords);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I assumed:

- Your text never will be `null`
- Your text matches regex `^(hello|how|are|you)$`
- Your words must be sorted